# Python: open all files with specific suffix, np.load

Tags: python, linux

I need to open all files with the "references" prefix:

```
import numpy as np
ex1= np.load("/scratch/abc/results/references_*")
```

Written this way I get an error:

````
No such file or directory: "/scratch/abc/results/references_* 
```"
````

Answer (score 0):

`np.load()` from NumPy does not support loading multiple files using a widcard.
Try loading the paths in an array with a module like glob or any other method, like so:

```
import numpy as np
import glob

file_paths = glob.glob("/scratch/abc/results/references_*")

loaded_data = []

for file_path in file_paths:
    data = np.load(file_path)
    loaded_data.append(data)
```

`glob.glob()` retrieves a list of file paths that match the pattern "/scratch/abc/results/references_*". Then, you loop through each file path, load its data using `np.load()`, and store the data in the list `loaded_data`. After the loop, `loaded_data` will contain the data from all the files with the "references" prefix.

Answer (score 0):

```
numpy.load(file, mmap_mode=None, allow_pickle=False, fix_imports=True, encoding='ASCII')[source]
Load arrays or pickled objects from .npy, .npz or pickled files.
```

you can only load one npy file at same time.

```
    from pathlib import Path
    import numpy as np

    res = []
    for f in Path('/scratch/abc/results/').glob('*.npy'):
        res.append(np.load(str(f)))
```